# ELF: How to print the r_info field?

Tags: gcc, elf

I want to list the name of all relocation entries which have the type **R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT**. Here's what I have so far:

```
char *str = (char *) (mapped_file + dynstr->sh_offset);

Elf64_Rela *reloc_entry = (Elf64_Rela *) (mapped_file + rela_plt->sh_offset);

for (i = 0; i < rela_plt->sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Rela); ++i)
{
       if (ELF64_R_TYPE(reloc_entry[i].r_info) == R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT)
                printf("name: %s\n", str + ELF64_R_SYM(reloc_entry[i].r_info));

}
```

The **ELF64_R_TYPE** macro is working fine but I'm having problems retrieving the relocation name with **ELF64_R_SYM**.

**readelf** shows the relocations correctly:

```
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x588 contains 3 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000004018  000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 puts@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
000000004020  000300000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
000000004028  000600000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
```

My code for some reason doesn't print the symbol name, instead it prints:

```
name: ibc.so.6
name: bc.so.6
name: so.6
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you solve the string table index?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer you men the symbol table index right? AFAIK the strings are in the .dynstr so I use an index into that section to get the string, which is in the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r_info` contains the symbol *index*, which is an array index for the symbol table. The array elements are of type `Elf32_Sym` or `Elf64_Sym`. The string table index of the symbol name is in the `st_name` member. This additional indirection is necessary because in general, binding a symbol requires more data than just its name.

Comment: was struggling with this for days, I think they could've been more clear about this on the man pages. Thanks Florian